# Scrolling to anchor in a div jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, parallax, smoothing

I got some problems with a smooth scroll to anchors in a parallax div with a fixed nav.

The script works fine from the top of the page but once in the content, links drive to bad anchors...

I tried several scripts but encounter the same problem (works fine from top but fails from content).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".scroll").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash) {
        //get rid of hash
        var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

        //get the position of the <a name> 
        var $toElement = $("[id=" + hash + "]");
        var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top;

        //scroll/animate that element
        $(".parallax").animate({
            scrollTop: toPosition
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

});

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/63hy5urr/1/

kindly please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check where `.parallax` is currently scrolled at by using the `scrollTop()` method and then add this value to `toPosition` when animating:

```
$(".parallax").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".parallax").scrollTop() + toPosition
}, 500);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63hy5urr/3/

Comment: Great. Thank you! = )